# Cannot select certain authors for posts after import

Tags: posts, multisite, users, author, import

I just consolidated a couple standalone WordPress installs into one Multi-site install. After importing posts into each site accordingly, I am unable to edit a post or page, and select a different user.

There are four users on the site, and I'm only able to select two of the four users as the post author.

Any idea why this would be happening? I'm pretty savvy with WordPress, but this one puzzles me.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Are the users _authors_ in that blog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, thanks to [`@Toscho`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/73/toscho) giving me the spark of an idea. We are using custom user roles and capabilities. It had something to do with the [User Role Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-role-editor/) plugin. Deleted the custom role, and created a new one, reassigning all capabilities. Then updating all users to the newly created user role. Problem fixed.

Not sure why that happened, but for anyone else who may use this plugin or run into this issue, this is a fix that worked for me.